# Linear Algebra: How do I find the total trips for each area given the 24 hours limit. [See problem below]

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

*You run a delivery company, delivering in three different areas of
Manhattan, A, B, and C. On average, a trip to the area  takes 4 hours, 5
gallons of fuel and you deliver 3 tons of goods. A trip to area B takes 6
hours, 4 gallons of fuel and you deliver 1 ton of goods. Finally, a trip to area
C takes 3 hours, 2 gallons of fuel and you deliver 3 tons of goods. Every day
your company delivers through all 24 hours, and your budget allows you to
spend 16 gallons in total, to deliver 24 tons of goods. How many trips to
each area can you do every day?*

I have constructed a Matrix for all this data but I don't understand how will I find the trips/day. I am currently studying systems of linear equations in Linear Algebra(in university) and this is the most confusing problem I have come across. Would appreciate all the help I can get :D

Comment: Hi! Did you try just having your truck delivering to only A? Is it feasible? What about only B? Only C? Rather than trying to attack the problem with the machinery of linear algebra upfront, you're probably better off just trying things out (a technique, incidentally, students should probably be taught to do more often). And the scale of the problem makes this entirely practical.

Comment: @BrianTung Yes! I took that route and got my answer after solving it through Matrix and Row Reduction methods. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes the most difficult part of such a problem is identifying your variables. In this case, the number of trips to areas $A$, $B$, and $C$ are the unknowns, which you could just call by names such as $t_A$, $t_B$, and $t_C$, respectively.

Now, each of the three constraints describes an equation. For example, the *hours* equation is $4t_A + 6t_B + 3t_C = 24$. You can similarly write down an equation in the same variables for *gallons of fuel* and *tons of cargo*. Remember that any time you add, subtract, or set equal two expressions that represent real world quantities **they have to have the same units.**

Stack these equations up, and you have a system of equations in a standard form, which you should be able to convert to a matrix-vector equation.
*Hint:* The matrix $M$ will have columns corresponding to the (three) variables plus one more *augmented* column, and it will have rows corresponding to the (three) constraint equations.

Does this make sense?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I followed your approach and got to my solution and understood the logic behind the question.